# Get tag name of XML element that has a "name" property

Tags: xml, powershell

```
$x = ([xml]"<sample name='notsample'/>").sample
```

Given the above line of code, as is, I want to find the name of the tag described by the `XmlElement` in `$x`. Typically, you would just use `$x.Name`, but the `name` attribute masks it. Instead of returning `sample`, `$x.name` returns `notsample`.

The only workaround I've found is:

```
[Xml.XmlElement].GetProperty("Name").GetValue($x)
```

... but this is hacky. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get it by invoking the property getter method directly:

```
$x.get_Name()
```

This works in many other similar cases. For example, if a type implements `IDictonary` and has other properties, you may need to use this to access those properties. By default, PowerShell does a lookup into the dictionary rather than getting/setting the accessed property.

You can get PowerShell to show hidden members like these using the `-Force` option on `Get-Member`:

```
$x | gm -Force
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are after is the `LocalName` property of the `XmlElement` class. Try:

```
PS> $x.LocalName
sample
```

> Gets the local name of the current node.
>
> Property Value
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The name of the current node with the prefix removed. For example, LocalName is **book** for the element `<bk:book>`.

Source: [MSDN: XmlElement.LocalName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.localname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: And what if there's an attribute named `LocalName`? It still would be hidden.

Comment: Well true, but `Name` is far more likely to be used as an attribute-name than `LocalName`..